# How do i check for null before applying string operation?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
var list = document.Root.Descendants(ns + "rect").Select(e => new {
            Style = e.Attribute("style").Value.Substring(16,6),
            Transform= e.Attribute("transform").Value.Substring(18, 43),
            Width = e.Attribute("width").Value,
            Height = e.Attribute("height").Value,
            X = e.Attribute("x").Value
        });
```

Not every "rect" have the Attribute "transform".
So i need somehow to check for null.

And how can i use Substring to get all the string i need ?
If there is Attribute "transform" for example transform="matrix(0.98125852,-0.1926959,0.1926959,0.98125852,0,0)" then i need to extract the numbers: 0.98125852,-0.1926959,0.1926959,0.98125852,0,0 and put each number in a int variable. The problem is that the way i'm using substring now is fine if the last two numbers are 0,0 but they might be other numbers in other cases.

The code now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace SvgParser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public enum Rects
        {
            WIDTH, HEIGHT, X, Y, COLOR, ANGLE
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ColumnHeader columnHeader1 = new ColumnHeader();
            columnHeader1.Text = "Column1";
            this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new ColumnHeader[] { columnHeader1 });           
            this.listView1.View = View.Details;

            ParseXml();
        }

        private void ParseXml()
        {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\mysvg\Documents\my.svg");
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

            var list = document.Root.Descendants(ns + "rect").Select(e => new {
                Style = e.Attribute("style").Value.Substring(16, 6),
                Transform = e.Attribute("transform")?.Value,
                Width = e.Attribute("width").Value,
                Height = e.Attribute("height").Value,
                X = e.Attribute("x").Value
            });

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                string result = string.Format("Width: {0}, Height: {1}, X: {2}", item.Width, item.Height, item.X);
                if (item.Transform != null)
                {
                    string transform = item.Transform;

                    // figure out the substring parameters
                    int start = "matrix(".Length;
                    int end = transform.LastIndexOf(")") - start;

                    // grab the values, by using split
                    string[] collection = transform.Substring(start, end).Split(',');

                    // an object to hold your results
                    List<decimal> results = new List<decimal>();

                    // iterate through the values (string) and try to convert it to a decimal
                    for (int i = 0; i < collection.Length; i++)
                    {
                        decimal.TryParse(collection[i], out decimal result);
                        results.Add(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But i'm getting now 3 errors. On the line:

```
decimal.TryParse(collection[i], out decimal result);
```

On the decimal and result:

```
Invalid expression term 'decimal'
```

And 
    Syntax error, ',' expected

And error on the line:

```
results.Add(result);
```

On the result:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'decimal'

Then i change the out part to: out result

```
decimal.TryParse(collection[i], out result);
```

Now the error is:

Argument 2: cannot convert from 'out string' to 'out decimal'

Comment: You changed my variable called `string transform` to `string result`.... This is why it's not working.... because `string result` conflicts with `decimal result` in the same block

Comment: x is a double so use : double? inclass definition.  Then instead of value use : X = (double?)e.Attribute("x")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Checking for null

```
Transform= e.Attribute("transform")?.Value.Substring(18, 43),
```

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44340111/3645638

---

### Using the Sub-string.

To answer your question on how to deal with the string, try this

```
// the string you want to grab the values from
string transform = "matrix(0.98125852,-0.1926959,0.1926959,0.98125852,0,0)";

// figure out the substring parameters
int start = "matrix(".Length;
int end = transform.LastIndexOf(")") - start;

// grab the values, by using split
string[] collection = transform.Substring(start,end).Split(',');

// an object to hold your results
List<decimal> results = new List<decimal>();

// iterate through the values (string) and try to convert it to a decimal
for (int i = 0; i < collection.Length; i++)
{
    decimal.TryParse(collection[i], out decimal result);
    results.Add(result);
}
```

this will result in a `List<decimal>` called `results` with the values

```
0.98125852
-0.1926959
0.1926959
0.98125852
0
0
```

---

#### Additional Information

As per your comments... This code block here

```
for (int i = 0; i < collection.Length; i++)
{
    decimal.TryParse(collection[i], out decimal result);
    results.Add(result);
}
```

is the equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < collection.Length; i++)
{
    decimal result; // note I am creating a new decimal (defaults to 0)
    decimal.TryParse(collection[i], out result);
    results.Add(result);
}
```

---

## Your Error

> ```
> string result = string.Format("Width: {0}, Height: {1}, X: {2}", item.Width, item.Height, item.X);
> ```

you can't have `string result` then declare `decimal result` below it again...  my example calls it `transform`

Comment: @DanielLip Too bad you can't accept two answers. Haha

Comment: @DanielLip the code works fine, make sure you didn't make any edits to it.

Comment: You can't make out decimal result i'm getting errors. And if i'm doing only out result then error cannont convert from out string to out decimal. All this part of code i added inside a foreach loop where i loop over the list. Edited my question with the part of code.

Comment: @DanielLip - I'll add some additional code to help you understand.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. It's working now fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DanielLip - I'd think my answer is more appropriate to your question now.

Comment: Indeed you deserve it.

Answer (score 3):

If you use C# 6.0, you can use the null conditional `?.` operator:

```
 Transform= e.Attribute("transform")?.Value.Substring(18, 43),
```

Comment: @DanielLip That has nothing to do with the Framework version. You can still use the new compiler.

Comment: @DanielLip what version of visual studio are you using? if it is 2014 or newer you should be able to do it by going in to your project advanced settings and raising the C# version it is compiled with. You can use .? with any version of .NET, all you need is VS2014 or newer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ternary operator.

```
Transform = (e.Attribute("transform") != null) ? e.Attribute("transform").Value.Substring(18, 43) : null,
```

Comment: transform is all the time null. After this part i'm doing a foreach over the list: foreach (var item in list)
        { if (item.Transform != null)
            {
                string transform = item.Transform;
            }
        } but item.Transform is null all the time and i'm sure there are parts rect have transform.

Answer (score 0):

Use safe navigation operator (?.):

```
var list = document.Root.Descendants(ns + "rect").Select(e => new {
            Style = e.Attribute("style").Value?.Substring(16,6),
            Transform= e.Attribute("transform").Value?.Substring(18, 43),
            Width = e.Attribute("width").Value,
            Height = e.Attribute("height").Value,
            X = e.Attribute("x").Value
        });
```